# fn + backspace (delete) works just at the second time as expected

Tags: keyboard, macos

I'm facing a weird misbehavior on my MacBook Pro (Retina).
I switched the operating language from German to English several days ago. Since then, I can't use the "delete" button (`fn + backspace`) anymore as before the language-change.

Whenever I press `delete` (`fn + backspace`), the button behaves as I wouldn't press the `fn` button (so just a regular `backspace`), but if I keep a finger on the `fn` button, and press the `backspace` button again, then the next letter will be deleted (a regular deletion, which is my intention).

Is this a bug, or something I can change by settings?

My operating system is: macOS Sierra 10.12.3